# snapshot.data returns null even though the realtime database has values

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

i am trying to build an IoT monitoring app to moniture temperature, soil humidity, etc. im keeping the data from the sensor in flutter realtime database but somehow it is returning null.
Im posting the entire code incase i have errors somewhere.

my flutter code:

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:percent_indicator/circular_percent_indicator.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'firebase_options.dart';
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override


  double _temperature = 0.0;
  double _soilMoisture = 0.0;
  double _humidity = 0.0;
  bool _pumpStatus = false;

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    @override


  /*  Future<void> _getData() async {
      final DataSnapshot snapshot = await _database.child('Sensor').get();
      final data = snapshot.value as Map<String, dynamic>;
      setState(() {
        _temperature = data['temperature'];
        _soilMoisture = data['soil_moisture'];
        _humidity = data['humudity'];
        print(_temperature);
      });
    }


    () async{
      await _getData();
      print('fgyev');
    };*/

    void initState() {
      super.initState();
    }
    return MaterialApp(

      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('IoT Smart Farm'),
          centerTitle: true,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
            child: StreamBuilder(
                stream: FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref().onValue,
                builder:(context,AsyncSnapshot<DatabaseEvent>snapshot){
                  print(snapshot.data);
                  if(snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data!=null) {
                    final data = Map<dynamic, dynamic>.from(
                        (snapshot.data as DatabaseEvent).snapshot.value
                        as Map<dynamic, dynamic>);
                    var value = data['Sensor'];
                    // setState(() {


                      _temperature = value['temperature'] / 100;
                      _humidity = value['humudity'] / 100;
                      _soilMoisture = value['soil_moisture'] / 100;
                      var motor = data['Motor'];
                      _pumpStatus = motor['inOn'];
                    // });
                  }

                  return Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                    children: <Widget>[

                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          BoxWidget(
                            color: Colors.blue,
                            percent: _soilMoisture,
                            title: 'SOIL MOISTURE',
                          ),
                          BoxWidget(
                            color: Colors.green,
                            percent: _temperature,
                            title: 'SOIL TEMPERATURE',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0),

                      Row(
                        children: <Widget>[
                          BoxWidget(
                            color: Colors.red,
                            percent: 0.50,
                            title: 'AIR TEMPERATURE',
                          ),
                          BoxWidget(
                            color: Colors.orange,
                            percent: _humidity,
                            title: 'AIR HUMIDITY',
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0),

                      Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Text(
                            'PUMP STATUS',
                            style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(width: 16.0),
                          Switch(
                            value: _pumpStatus,
                            onChanged: (value) {},
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                      SizedBox(height: 16.0),
                    ],
                  );
                }
            ),
           
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

the json file of database is:

```
  "Motor": {
    "inOn": false
  },
  "Sensor": {
    "humudity": 84.6,
    "soil_moisture": 80,
    "temperature": 20
  }
}
```

I'm not sure why it's returning null. The reference clearly exists. Can someone point it out?

Comment: can you make sure you are receiving data[that you've attached] inside your if state? try debug/print to verify it

Comment: When the data comes in from the database, you add it to the state of the widget. Yet you commented out the call to `setState(() {` that is required when you change the state of a widget.

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i am not receiving the data inside if state. the snapshot.data is null. which was my question.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen it still doesnt work. the snapshot.data is null.

Comment: can you include your console database screenshot